# free -h command in ubuntu minimal

Tags: xfce, xfce4-terminal

I run `free -h` on Ubuntu minimal with XFCE and the output is misaligned.

[image: output]

Why does it look misaligned?
On Ubuntu standard, the output is aligned properly.

Comment: Instead of pasting a giant image of a screenshot (that's too big to read even), just copy the text and paste it, then use the "Code Sample Ctrl+K" formatting

Comment: What does "messy" mean? Looks like it's not in English, is that the problem?

Comment: the problem is that the output looks dissordered

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Looks like [a bug related to the language](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/1380380). Try running `LC_ALL=C free`

Comment: ubuntu 18.00 LTS

Comment: LC_ALL=C  work fine but the output is in English, i want the output in Spanish

Comment: That's definitely the bug I linked to, there's even a fix there (editing a language file somehow, read & try it if you're interested). Bugs are off-topic here unfortunately, so this question should really be closed